# Force Toolbar Search to Lose Focus After Search on Mobile to Hide Keyboard

Tags: mobile, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using free jqgrid on a mobile site with toolbar search.

The toolbar search is working but the keyboard on the phone stays active and covers the grid.

How can I configure jqgrid, so after the user clicks on Enter or Go button on the mobile phone, the toolbar search field will lose focus and phone keyboard will disappear and display the grid.

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetFilteredData.htm

My first attempt was too blur the toolbar after the search and it did not work using the following

```
.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
            searchOperators: true, afterSearch: function () {
                var s;
        s = jQuery("#jqGrid").blur();
    },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tired just calling the focus method on the grid and this makes the keyboard on the mobile phone disappear after pressing on the Go button to start the search.

```
.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
        searchOperators: true, afterSearch: function () {
            var s;
            s = jQuery("#jqGrid").blur();
            },
      });
```